# QtConcurrent error: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I'd like to run simple method in a different thread than the GUI thread inside my Qt application. To do this I'm using [QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) and [Qt Concurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html). However, I ran into a compile error:

```
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h(58): error C2280: 'QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<T>::RunFunctionTask(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h(121): note: compiler has generated 'QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<T>::RunFunctionTask' here
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h(121): note: 'QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<T>::RunFunctionTask(void)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member 'QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<T>::result' has either no appropriate default constructor or overload resolution was ambiguous
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h(120): note: see declaration of 'QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<T>::result'
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h(58): note: while compiling class template member function 'QtConcurrent::StoredFunctorCall0<T,T (__cdecl *)(void)>::StoredFunctorCall0(FunctionPointer)'
        with
        [
            T=Error,
            FunctionPointer=Error (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent\qtconcurrentrun.h(74): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'QtConcurrent::StoredFunctorCall0<T,T (__cdecl *)(void)>::StoredFunctorCall0(FunctionPointer)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Error,
            FunctionPointer=Error (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtConcurrent\qtconcurrentrun.h(74): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QtConcurrent::StoredFunctorCall0<T,T (__cdecl *)(void)>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
C:\Users\dalji\Documents\Dev\TestQtConcurrent\main.cpp(37): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'QFuture<Error> QtConcurrent::run<Error>(T (__cdecl *)(void))' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Error
        ]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
16:14:59: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project TestQtConcurrent (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit)
When executing step "Build"
```

Here is a simple test application that reproduces the issue I'm having

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

class Error
{
public:
    enum class ErrorType {
        NoError,
        FileSavingError,
        FileLoadingError
    };
    Error(ErrorType errorType, const QString &errorMessage  = "") :
        m_errorType(errorType),
        m_errorMessage(errorMessage)
    {

    }
    const QString &errorMessage() const { return m_errorMessage; }
    ErrorType errorType() const {  return m_errorType; }

private:
    ErrorType m_errorType;
    QString m_errorMessage;
};


Error testMethod(){
    return Error(Error::ErrorType::NoError, "No Error");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFuture<Error> errorFuture = QtConcurrent::run(testMethod);
    return a.exec();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error messages often comes with informational notes. Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into your question.

Comment: You are missing a default constructor for `Error`. Add e.g. `Error() : m_errorType(ErrorType::NoError) {}`

Comment: Why is a default constructor needed?

Comment: While you should always include the complete build output when you ask about build errors, in this case MSVC is less than helpful and doesn't really state out loud that a default constructor is needed. Other compilers (like e.g. GCC) give more long-winded error messages but at least state that a default constructor is needed.

Comment: Nothing in the docs says it must have one, this was just the quickest way I could come up with to get it to compile at all (hence, not an answer).

Comment: Read `QFuture` reference, *The result can be of any type that has a default constructor and a copy constructor.* [ref](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, and as indicated in the error message itself, the problem is that your `Error` class has no default constructor.

While there is nothing explicit in the [documentation for `QtConcurrentRun`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) that indicates this requirement, there is the following in the [documentation for QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) (bold emphasis mine)<sup>1</sup>:

> QFuture allows threads to be synchronized against one or more results
> which will be ready at a later point in time. The result can be of
> ***any type that has a default constructor*** and a copy constructor. …

The simplest way to add the required default constructor to your `Error` class is to add a default value for the first argument (you already have one for the second argument) in your currently-defined constructor (I've assumed that the `ErrorType::NoError` enumeration is a sensible value for this default):

```cpp
    Error(ErrorType errorType = ErrorType::NoError, const QString& errorMessage = "") :
        m_errorType(errorType),
        m_errorMessage(errorMessage)
    {
    }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that, for your `Error` class, the (also required) [copy constructor is implicitly declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and will be generated for you, by the compiler.